Measuring Impedance of a PCB Antenna Trace
I need to verify if the antenna trace on my PCB is properly matched to 50 ohms. I have a network analyzer (PicoVNA 108), calibration tool (SOLT with SMA on each port) and calibrated cables with SMA connectors, but the PCB lacks any SMA ports. To connect the network analyzer, I need to solder a 50-ohm coaxial cable directly to the antenna trace. At this point, I think that I have three options:

Solder a halfwave length additional cable (only one end has SMA connector) to PCB. Connect calibrated cable to the soldered cable. Then in the settings of the VNA adjust the reference plane (if it does not have such option just measure it like that).
Solder a SMA connector to the PCB (This will be challenging but I think it is doable). Then use the calibrated cables without addition.
Calibrate the VNA with the additional cable (has SMA connector on both ends) attached. Then remove SMA on one end and connect it to the PCB.

Please inform me if my thoughts are nonsense or impractical.
